# Jersey File Upload

Tags: file, file-upload, jersey, inputstream

I tried to upload a file to my jersey server, but there is an error.

```
 Writer output = null;
    File file = null;
    try {
      String text = "Rajesh Kumar";
      file = new File("write.txt");
      output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        is.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart().field("file", is, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
    System.out.println(is);
    System.out.println(tenant1.getTenantId());
    System.out.println(part);
    String response = service.path("rest").path("file").type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(String.class, part);
```

The Syso are not null. So the File was written to the inputstream.

Error:

```
ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: ReadError , when I send it to the server.
```

Server Side:

```
@POST
@Path("/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postFileTenant(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream) throws IOException {

    // save it

    return Response.ok(IOUtils.toString(stream)).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an InputStream that is closed so obviously Jersey runtime can't read from it. Remove `is.close();` line from your code.